# How to call a function present in my service?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, rxjs, karma-jasmine

I have a component named signup It consist of signup.service.ts where i have written the code to post data into database I want to write test case to call the function from the service but not able to understand how to call it ?
            I have tried the following test case but getting error

Following is the test case written to call service

```
    it('should call service',()=>{

        let value={
           username:"xxxx",
            firstName:"xxxx",
            lastName:"xxxxx",
             mobileNumber:"56456545",
            email:"xxx@gmail.com",
             password:"xxx",
             confirmPassword :"xxx"
        }

        const quoteService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(Signup2Service);
        fixture.detectChanges();
        spyOn(quoteService, 'register');
        expect(quoteService.register(value)).toBeFalsy();
       })
```

Below is my **signup.service.ts**

```
        import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
        import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
        import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
        import { config } from "config";
        const baseUrl: string = config.url;


        @Injectable()
        export class Signup2Service {
            constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


            register(value): Promise<any> {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    this.http.post(baseUrl + "user/register", value)
                        .pipe(map(Response => Response))

                        .subscribe((res: Response) => {
                            console.log("XXXXXXXXX Update  Response ", res);
                            console.log("res = ", res);
                        });
                });
        }

        }
```

Comment: Why are u using `Promise` wrapped above `Observable` ??  I am suggesting diff approach, let me know if it is ok . Also share he part where you have called `register` method of that service

Comment: Any update on my provided answer ?

Comment: It worked for me but know i am getting some issues related to routing

Comment: ok, can u please mark it as an answer (by clicking tick button) and let me know the link of that another issue which you are facing, I'll try to look into that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is my article which covers all such basic testing scenarios](https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/say-hi-to-jasmine-karma-in-angular-intro-d728d669a1c7) to start with. [There is another article which specifically talks about this case](https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/testing-a-component-with-stub-services-and-spies-in-jasmine-1428d4242a49?source=post_page---------------------------).  Feel free to provide your feedback

To start with, create a `Stub` service rather than calling the actual one which is calling Database.

In **signup.service.ts**

```
 register(value): observable<any> {
     return this.http.post(baseUrl + "user/register", value)
        .pipe(map(Response => Response))
 }
```

Lets say you have `register` called in component as :

```
 constructor(public signup2Service: Signup2Service){}

 submitForm(data){
     this.showSomeSpinnerFlag = true
     this.signup2Service.register(data).subscribe(res => { 
       this.showSomeSpinnerFlag = false;
    })
 }
```

***Make sure to have `signup2Service` as `public` in component `constructor`***

---

Now for testing:

**signup.service.stub..ts**

```
export class Signup2ServiceStub{
    register(someVal){
      return of({
         whatever_property_expected: ''
      })
    }
}
```

In `component.spec` use `useClass` as below:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
     declarations: [ WhateverComponent],
     providers:    [ {provide: Signup2Service , useClass: Signup2ServiceStub} ]
});

it('should call service',()=>{
      let value={
           username:"xxxx",
            firstName:"xxxx",
            lastName:"xxxxx",
             mobileNumber:"56456545",
            email:"xxx@gmail.com",
             password:"xxx",
             confirmPassword :"xxx"
       };
    spyOn(component.signup2Service,'register').and.callThrough();
    component.showSomeSpinnerFlag = true;
    component.submitForm(value);
    expect(component.signup2Service.register).toHaveBeenCalledWith(value);
    expect(component.showSomeSpinnerFlag).toBeFalsy();
})
```